# jQuery manipulation of duplicate tags

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Ok, this is a weird request, but I need to use jQuery to manipulate a bunch of tags that all have the same id and name.

We're using Izenda AdHoc reporting controls, which has a query designer GUI. It gives you a select dropdown with a list of tables in it, and you can click a button and get another one, and another and another etc. to build your query.

Every time you click for a new table it posts back to the server, and comes back with a new row in the table, with the same controls as the row above, including an identical select tag, with the same id and name attributes. How ASP.NET is generating this is beyond me.

But I was using jQuery to modify the length of the dropdowns as they are too short. Strangely enough, even though they all have the same id, using jQuery like:

```
jQuery("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_queryBuilder_ctl101_jtc_Table").width(250);
```

will only change the first dropdown. I need to widen them all, but they all have the same ID. And there are lots of other select tags I *dont* want to touch.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Now that I think about it, I have no idea how this even works. The page poasts back, saves the datasources etc. everything seems to work, but I have no idea how ASP.NET tells one dropdown from another. But it does work.

Comment: HTML id's should always be unique.  You can always use a class to mark multiple related elements, but duplicate id's cause problems with scripting.

Of course, when you don't control the code... that's another story.  Maybe you can use jQuery to assign new, unique id's to the added elements?

Comment: I agree with you. But in this case we have an apparently buggy 3rd party control that we have no control over.

Comment: Can you post some of the markup for this? Maybe you could select the parents (unless their IDs are also non-unique...), and then traverse to the children you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#yourid")` will only match the first one (since, of course, all your IDs should be the unique).

If you can't have unique IDs then it's possible to access them using the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
`$("input[id='yourid']");`. This will return all of the matching elements.

See it working : http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/22mpK/

Comment: awesome, thanks! I assume that the attribute equals thing wasn't intended to be used with id since we're supposed to have unique ids, but it seems to work like any other attribute. works great!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access them via some other selector. since the javascript specs call for unique ID's, jQuery will only act on the first matching unique ID. If there's a class higher up the DOM and you can consistently reach your element via some DOM-related path, you may want to attack your problem that way. 
such as have each table render in a div of class "whateverClass" and use `$('.whateverClas table').width(250);`
I'd have to do some testing, but the only other solution I could think of would be to do a looped `$("#ELEM").not(".classed").addClass("classed");` to give each duplicate ID a selectable class..?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very surprising the jQuery only adjusts one of your selects.

DOM IDs should be unique across a page, and even though browsers do not complain too much about it, selecting elements by ID in javascript will only give you random results if several elements have the same ID.

you should try selecting the tables via their element names and position in the page.

```
for instance let's imagine your tables are inside the 3rd div in the page :
jQuery('div:eq(2)>table').width(250);
```

you should take a look at all the structural selectors available on [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and build a structural selector without using the ID.

I hope this will help you

Jerome Wagner